# Convert JSON array object to String in Powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, convertto-json

I am working with a JSON like that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Ack":  "no",
        "Rule":  "dont",
        "Tags":  [
                     "server"
                 ],
        "Type":  "blue"
    },

    {
        "Ack":  "no1",
        "Rule":  "knock",
        "Tags":  [
                     "yellow",
                     "green"
                 ],
        "Type":  "multiplecolour"
    }

]
```

I need to convert the Tags array into a comma-separated string [and replace the array with the converted string in the JSON file].  I have tried converting from JSON, but I am struggling to convert the array into string in a clean way, still learning PS so please bear with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) may work for you.  Here's an example of converting your JSON string to an array of PowerShell objects, then joining the tags for each object with a comma delimiter:

```
$json = @"
[
    {
        "Ack":  "no",
        "Rule":  "dont",
        "Tags":  [
                     "server"
                 ],
        "Type":  "blue"
    },
    {
        "Ack":  "no1",
        "Rule":  "knock",
        "Tags":  [
                     "yellow",
                     "green"
                 ],
        "Type":  "multiplecolour"
    }
]
"@

(ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json) `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.Tags = ($_.Tags -join ","); $_ } `
    | ConvertTo-Json `
    | Out-File -FilePath new.json
```

EDIT: Note (as @mklement0 points out), the parentheses around `ConvertFrom-Json` are required to [force the enumeration of the results as an array](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424) of objects through the pipeline.

Comment: Nice, though it's worth pointing out that `(...)` is _required_, because it forces enumeration of the [array that `ConvertFrom-Json` sends _as a whole_ through the pipeline](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).

Comment: @mri.o: Please state all requirements up front in the future - it is not clear from your question as currently stated. Perhaps Glenn is willing to update his answer, but the short of it is that you must  use `$_.Tags = $_.Tags -join ","` instead, and pipe to `ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: $jsonParameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content)         
 $jsonParameters | ForEach-Object { $_.Tags -join "," } | ConvertTo-Json | out-file new.json - this is how I piped it, the content of new.json is only the tag strings.  @Glenn. It doesn't create it properly.

Comment: @mri.o So, your intent is to reproduce the JSON with the only difference being that "Tags" is no longer an array, but a string property, which contains one or more comma-delimited values?  For example, it becomes this for the second array element?
`"Tags": "yellow,green"`

Comment: If so, the latest update to the answer should work for you.

Comment: Learnt something new today, thanks @Glenn, latest update works!